# Can boolean operators be used with the preprocessor?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I wondering if it possible to have a preprocessor OR or AND statement?  I have this code where I want to run under `_DEBUG` or `_UNIT_TEST` tags(?).

What I want is something like the following:

```
#if _DEBUG || _UNIT_TEST
  //Code here
#endif
```

If this is not possible, is there a workaround to achieve the same thing without having to duplicate the code using a `#elseif`?

Comment: You can also do `#define WHATEVER true`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
#if defined _DEBUG || defined _UNIT_TEST 
  //Code here 
#endif
```

You could use AND and NOT operators as well. For instance:

```
#if !defined _DEBUG && defined _UNIT_TEST 
  //Code here 
#endif
```

Comment: may I use the `or` instead of `||` like in c++ code? like `#if (defined(_MSC_VER) or (defined(__GNUC__) and (7 <= __GNUC_MAJOR__))`? when I tested (msvc 2022), it does not work.

Answer (score 16):

`#if` takes *any* C++ expression of integral type(1) that the compiler manages to evaluate at compile time. So yes, you can use `||` and `&&`, as long as you use `defined(SOMETHING)` to test for definedness.

(1): well, it's a bit more restricted than that; for the nitty-gritty see the restrictions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx) (at *"with these additional restrictions"*).

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Using "defined(SOMETHING)" isn't always what you want. For example, it could be that the symbol is defined as '0' or as '1'. That means it is always defined.

Answer (score 14):

```
#if defined(_DEBUG) || defined(_UNIT_TEST)
  //Code here
#endif
```

Also for the record, it's `#elif`, not `#elseif`.

Comment: FYI, identifiers/names, including preprocessor symbols, beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter (or beginning with two underscores) are reserved to the implementation by the C and C++ standards; they shouldn't really be used in "ordinary" code.